# Can you explain this odd ES6 arrow function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

using TypeScript:

```
public subscribe:(subscribeFunction:(state)=>void)=>()=>void;
```

It's a subscribe method that gets function as an argument, of type function, and that function given, will receive a state argument when called, that argumented function will not return anything (i.e.: void) ... and I am lost on the last `()=>()=>void`.

Do I understand this right?

Comment: Incidentally, nobody should ever be writing confusing code like this. If it’s hard to read, break it up! `type VoidFunction = { (): void; }; subscribe: { (subscribeFunction: (state) => void): VoidFunction; }`, for example.

Answer (score 8):

It's for a public property called `subscribe` that has a type of `(subscribeFunction: (state) => void) => () => void;`:

```
// scope
public
// name
subscribe:
// type (function)
    // parameters
    (
        // parameter name
        subscribeFunction:
        // parameter type (function)
        (state) => void
    ) => 
    // return type (function)
    () => void;
```

Here's an example that compiles:

```
class MyClass {
    public subscribe: (subscribeFunction: (state) => void) => () => void;
}

let myInstance = new MyClass();

myInstance.subscribe = (subscribeFunction: (state) => void) => {
    console.log("statements might go here");

    return () => {
        subscribeFunction(1 /* state */);
        console.log("nothing returned by this inner function");
    };
};

// Example use

// outputs "statements might go here"
let innerFunction = myInstance.subscribe((state) => console.log(state));
// outputs 1 and "nothing returned by this inner function"
innerFunction();
```

Comment: I always thought you do a :void for function that doesn't return anything, I guess multiple ways... tx!!!

Comment: @born2net yes, that's what it means. Here since the method has a return type of `() => void` it returns a function that doesn't return anything.

Comment: @born2net wow, I really messed up the original explanation. I missed the `:`... It's fixed now. Sorry about that.

Comment: I meant to say "function" in my first comment... it's not a method.

Comment: Your example code might get even better if you call the `subscribeFunction` with some state

Answer (score 0):

Notice the first colon -- `subscribe` is a public property of a function type, not a method. Unfolded:

```
public subscribe: // public property, which is
    ( // of the type of a function, which takes
        subscribeFunction: // 1 parameter, which itself is
        (state) => void // a function of 1 parameter, returning nothing
    ) => // and the upon invocation of a function stored in "subscribe" it
        () => void; // returns a function of no parameter and no return value
```

Thus, you can store a function into the `subscribe` property, then call it while giving it a function as a parameter, and as a result you will get another function, which you can subsequently call:

```
subscribe = (subscribeFunction: (state) => void) => {
    subscribeFunction('A');
    return () => {console.log('C');};
};
let subscribed = subscribe((state) => {
    console.log(state, 'B');
}); // prints 'A,B'
subscribed(); // prints 'C'
```

Answer (score 0):

tx for feedback,  now that I understand it I think its best explained as:

public subscribe: (subscribeFunction:(state)=>void)

// first potion is for subscribeFunction which will accept a function that does not return anything

=>()=>void;

// second potion is for the subscribe itself as it will return a function that does not return anything... and I agree, code like this should be more explicit